# How to get the 2D Array length

Tags: java

I create method to display element in the 2D array. but I can't specify the array length for each dimension. this is my code

```
public static void display2DArray(String[][] array){        
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Document "+i+ "  Section "+j);
            System.out.println(" "+array[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way

```
public static void display2DArray(String[][] array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Document "+i+ "  Section "+j);
            System.out.println(" "+array[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `i` and `j` should both default to 0. Second, change j to be `array[0].length`, and before have a check if array is empty, just return right away. An array can be represented as follows:

```
{{[0][0] [0][1] [0][2]},

 {[1][0] [1][1] [1][2]},

 {[2][0] [2][1] [2][2]}}
```

So to get the height, you just do `array.length`, but for width, you gotta get one of the interal arrays' `lengths`, so `array[0].length` will do

Answer (score 0):

In Java, every intrinsic array object (i.e. Object[]) has the "length" property.
If you have an object of type Object[][], you can view it as (Object[])[], meaning an array of arrays.
So what you do is use index "i" to get an inner array and then an index "j" to get an element from the inner array. Namely:

```
Object[][] myArray;

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i)
   for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; ++j)
   { /* do something with myArray[i][j] */ }
```